# Not able to provide support AppCompatActivity in eclipse

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I work with eclipse mars and i downloaded all the sdk version. But when i extends with AppCompatActivity, its says "AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved to a type". I struggle from 2 days to resolved it. I used Ubuntu 12.04 os version. 
I tried to add the jar file for compat v7 but no luck.
[image]

Comment: Use ANDROID STUDIO.

Comment: yes, use android studio instead.

Comment: Its requirement to use Eclipse.